# PJSIP Calls fail while calling a client over a different network

Tags: ios, iphone, voip, pjsip, kamailio

I have build a PJSIP app for VoIP.
Which works well when trying to connect a client which is using the same network.
I am maintaining the connection over TLS.

I have successfully configured RTPEnginge
And using Kamailio 4.3
I have tried all the methods on the PJSIP help site for getting through NAT.

I am able to connect the call with a client but unable to hear any audio.
Please help or suggest a way to solve this issue.
Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact reason could certainly be confirmed only by getting much more informations.

However, from your description, you may be simply missing a RTP relay: kamailio usually requires [rtpproxy](http://www.rtpproxy.org/) to be installed.

You will also need to configure kamailio (kamailio.cfg) to use rtpproxy.

Here is the documentation for kamailio's [rtpproxy module](http://kamailio.org/docs/modules/4.3.x/modules/rtpproxy.html).

Comment: I was using rtpproxy before, but as it doesn't support TLS i switched to rtp engine. 
and I have configured kamailio as the calls work accurately while bith the devices are connected over the same network.

Comment: I said that you have to configure kamailio to use *rtpproxy*. I understand that you already have configured kamailio...

Comment: You also said you want to support TLS, but... according to me, both rtpproxy and rtpengine don't have to care about data they relay. Both can relay, SRTP, DTLS-SRTP or RTP.

Comment: We were using rtpproxy with RTP before  and everything was working fine.
As I wanted to use SRTP i installed rtpengine and removed rtpproxy. 
As of now I am able to connect the call if the two devices are in the same network.
But if any of the device is in a different network I am unable to receive the audio.
is there any additional config we need to do?
This is my mail id Contact me there I will send you our log.
saurabh.sahastrabudhe@xpointers.com\

Comment: My service is using kamailio/rtpproxy and there is no issue with using SRTP!

Comment: hey... AymericM I am trying a similar voip application without security  and want to just connect it over TCP or even UDP .. the problem is that i am getting connected successfully with the receiver but i am unable to hear anything. no packet transfer as well. I have configured the kamailio with the basic config explained in the demo http://www.xianwenchen.com/blog/2014/06/16/how-to-make-an-ios-voip-app-with-pjsip-part-2/